# why is select much slower with left join+where

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to optimize a MySQL query that is taking a long time to process. Imagine we have two tables, a users table and a purchases table. Both tables have ~20,000 rows in them.

```
mysql> 
SELECT NOW(),u.id
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN purchases p
        ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE
        p.website_id = 1234
    ORDER BY u.total_paid DESC
    LIMIT 10;
+---------------------+-------+
| NOW()               | id    |
+---------------------+-------+
*snip*
+---------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Not super fast but pretty snappy. If I change nothing other than change `u.id` to `u.*` it will slow down dramatically:

```
mysql>
SELECT NOW(),u.*
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN purchases p
        ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE
        p.website_id = 1234
    ORDER BY u.total_paid DESC
    LIMIT 10;
+---------------------+-------+
*snip*
+---------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.37 sec)
```

Before you say "Well, you should never use `select *`" consider that it slowly creeps up to that length of time the more fields you add, i.e. naming half of the fields to select will cause the query execute in ~0.20 seconds and no field on the users table is larger than a `varchar(255)`.

However, if I take the ids from my relatively snappy query and I simply:

```
mysql>
SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE id IN (*snip*);
+---------------------+-------+
*snip*
+---------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So my two queries: `select u.id` plus `select u.* where id in` is faster than what I assume is a similar query. What the heck?

**More Info:** The users table has about 30 fields on it. Again, no field is larger than a `varchar(255)`

**More More Info:** The EXPLAIN for both queries is this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,user_id_index,website_id_index,website_user_id_index,website_created_index,website_type_created_index,website_type_index,purchase_user_id_type_index,user_id_website_id_index,website_id_user_id_index
          key: website_id_user_id_index
      key_len: 9
          ref: const
         rows: 9976
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: u
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: database.p.user_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

**Edit** Could it possibly be that since it's using temporary/filesort it has to select * from users, not knowing which rows will end up in the final result set? So it may seem like a trivial amount of extra data but in reality it's the difference between selecting a large chunk of the table? If this is correct, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at the `EXPLAIN` of each query? I'm guessing your `SELECT *` requires a scan of *more* rows.

Comment: I have, yes. Both are scanning 9976 rows and both are using the same `website_id_user_id_index` index.

Comment: Posting them here would help.

Comment: Just posted them (with a thought).

Comment: Without knowing if MySQL would show this in `EXPLAIN`: if querying only for `u.id`, MySQL does not need to look at the table at all, it can retrieve the values from the index-leafs. Selecting for `u.*` forces it to retrieve the table data, making the query slower. Apart from that, your query does not make much sense since you `outer join` first and then `filter` on `p`. This should not make a difference to the server but the query should either read `left join ... on p.user_id = u.id and p.website_id = 1234` without the `where`-clause or use an `inner join`.

Comment: @user2722968 Check out my answer below which I think does pretty much what you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to ask/partial answer.  What are you really asking for.  You have a LEFT-JOIN to the purchases table, but then have a WHERE clause for a particular "purchase" web site ID.  This is in essence bring the query to an INNER JOIN and only returning those users who DID purchase from the site in question.  That said, I would have re-written the query as

```
select 
      NOW(),
      u.id 
   from 
      purchases p
         JOIN users u 
            ON p.user_id = u.id
   where 
      p.website_id = 1234 
   order by 
      u.total_paid desc 
   limit 
      10;
```

assuming you have an index on (Website_ID), this will first start with purchases and join to users but ONLY for purchases on the website 1234.  This too might give a false answer as what happens if one user purchased multiple times from the same site, AND they were one of the top buyers... Their ID could come up multiple times.  To prevent this, I would pre-query with DISTINCT users from the site, THEN join to users.  I would have an index on the purchases table of (Website_ID, user_ID), then do the following.

```
select 
      NOW(),
      u.id 
   from 
      ( select distinct p.user_id
           from purchases p
           where p.website_id = 1234 ) PQ
         JOIN users u 
            ON PQ.user_id = u.id
   order by 
      u.total_paid desc 
   limit 
      10;
```